# ScrollView and SwitchPreferences at the bottom causes erratic behavior. Why does the list scroll up whenever I toggle a SwitchePreference?

Tags: android, android-preferences, switchpreference

Has anyone experienced this? When I press on a SwitchPreference, the ScrollView scrolls up. This never happens with any other preferences which include MultiSelectListPreference, Preference, and ListPreference.

Even with blank behavior (a listener has not been registered to the SwitchPreference), a successful toggle always causes the list to scroll up. And after 2 times of toggling it, the erratic scrolling behavior does not occur again until the activity is destroyed.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36941388 Could this be related?

Comment: Are you using the AndroidX Preference library? Or is this in the framework `android.preference` library?

Comment: I am using android.preference (but it is the compat library). The actual preference is SwitchPreferenceCompat. As for the other answer, I don't think it's the same thing I am experiencing. My issue is that when I press a Switch at the bottom, the ScrollView will jump to the top. The other people's issue is that the wrong Switch is being updated because it is sharing the same view.

Comment: My issue does not occur in some devices and emulators, but it does occur on my Nougat phone. I added empty dummy Switches and it does the same thing.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? It is recommended that you migrate over to the AndroidX library in any case, it's the evolution of the original compat libraries.

Comment: I'm going to migrate to AndroidX and see if this works!

Comment: Migrating to androidx.preference did not fix it.

Comment: Do you have a small sample application you can share? What does your preference xml look like? And what version of androidx are you using?

Comment: I fixed the problem by removing ScrollView and just using a LinearLayout as the parent for the fragment that hosted the PreferenceScreen/Preferences. Doing this immediately solved the problem. I assumed PreferenceScreen and/or LinearLayout would not have scrollable behavior by default, so I originally used a ScrollView as the parent. But it already works out of the box without having ScrollView as a parent.

Comment: Ohh, yeah - that makes sense :) AndroidX Preferences use a RecyclerView, so scrolling is automatically handled for you. Glad you figured it out!